# Risks with Foreign Key that references the primary key of the same table

Tags: sql, asp.net-mvc

I've inherited a project that has a table called `Users` that stores a unique ID for each user that has permissions to use an application.  That Table has the `User_ID`.  This table also has a column called `Mgr_User_ID` which tracks who the individual reports to.  I'd like to make the `User_ID` a foreign key of Column `Mgr_user_ID` so that I can access the managers information easily in the MVC project I'm working on that uses this table.

My question is basically, is this considered poor practice and are there any risks associated with doing something like this?

Comment: mgr_user_id will have to allow nulls or you can't insert your first record.

Comment: The table already exists.  None of the tables that were built have a lot of relationships and I'm sort of playing catch up on getting them in shape for using in a entity relationship model.  that is a fair point though, I'll keep it in mind if I need to build anything similar later.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Self-referencing tables are a pretty common practice. It's how you model any hierarchical relationship.

The biggest "risk", which isn't really a risk, is that if you're trying to walk the entire hierarchy (e.g. you want to create an organizational chart) you will need to write a recursive method (which can sometimes be a brain-twister if you're not used to it).

Also, decide in advance how you're going to identify the top of the hierarchy (i.e. the manager who doesn't report to anyone). In some systems the `Mgr_User_ID` is set to null and in others they decide to make it the same as the `User_ID`. I've worked with both approaches and there isn't really an advantage of one over the other, just make sure everyone working in the data understands the rule, and if you have any other relationships like this use the same approach for all of them.

Answer (score 0):

This is commonly called "self-join" of tables.  It is really common for an employee table or an organization table.  Whenever there is a hierarchy within in the rows of a table(worker -> manager, field office -> head quarter), self join can be used.

This is not a bad practice.  In fact, breaking an employee table to a worker table and a manager table would be worse practice.  As that would complicate things by managing essentially same objects in two tables.

However, querying a table using self join can be unintuitive and makes for a lengthy code.  You can make things easier by using views, though.  If you have an employee table that has Mgr_User_ID.  Maybe you can write a query like this and make it a view.  If you just want worker's name and manager's name in a single table:

```
CREATE VIEW dbo.DIMUser
AS 
SELECT Users.UserId
, Users.UserName
, MUsers.UserId AS ManagerId
, MUsers.UserName AS ManagerName
FROM dbo.Users AS Users
    LEFT JOIN dbo.Users AS MUsers
    ON Users.Mgr_User_ID = MUsers.Id
```